# CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll() is doing nothing (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native

I am calling the following function to save a remote file to the camera roll.

In the Libraries of my xcode-Project is a link to the CameraRoll-project (node_modues/...) and added it to the Link Binary With Libraries...

```
doit() {
      console.log('STARTING');
      CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll('https://example.com/img_web/pizza.jpg', 'photo').then(function(result) {
        console.log('save succeeded ' + result);
        alert(result);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('save failed ' + error);
        alert(error);
      });
      console.log('FINISHED');
    }
```

My console looks always like this:
STARTING  FINISHED

and in the Camera Roll are no new images...

If I change the URL to http:// instead of https:// and call the function, I get alert, that it's not possible to download the image because of security and so on... So something is happening in the background but the promises never get resolved...

Comment: Not sure about that implementation, but you need to have asked for the user’s authorisation to access the camera roll. Don’t remember offhand, you might actually need some specific keys in your info.plist for user-facing strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save images to users camera roll you need to add this line to your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description...</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

It only allows local files as of now, so you have to download in temp path and then give that path to save in camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this in your plist :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I added this line now, but now the app crashes or in Xcode there is an exception....

Comment: Can you post your plist?